# How can I parse this html content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm trying to parse the title and link of particular article from HTML page,

My code is as below,

```
 def get_bcci_articles():

        bcci_article_link = "http://www.bcci.tv/news/2018/news"

        r = requests.get(bcci_article_link)
        bcci_article_html = r.text

        soup = BeautifulSoup(bcci_article_html, "html.parser")
        # print(soup.prettify())

        bcci_items = soup.find_all("div",
                                        {"class": "newsCol"})
        bcci_article_dict = {}

        for div in bcci_items:
            a = div.find('a')['href']
            b = 'https://www.bcci.tv'
            c = urljoin(b,a)
            #print(c)
            bcci_article_dict[div.find('p')['class.title']] = c

        return bcci_article_dict
```

this is the html content

```
 <div class="newsCol">
<a href="/news/2018/news/17091/confident-india-u19-eye-fourth-world-cup-title">
<p class="title">Confident India U19 eye fourth World Cup title</p>
</a>
</div>
```

I want to extract link and title, I can extract link using div.find('a')['href'] , how can I extract class = "title" so I get,  Confident India U19 eye fourth World Cup title.
I tried by doing [div.find('p')['class.title']], i'm getting error I know this is not a right way of calling, how can I fix this??

Comment: `div.find('p', {"class":"title"})` -- just like you did in `find_all`.

Comment: {<p class="title">Domestic Interview</p>: 'https://www.bcci.tv/news/2017/domestic-interview/16920/vidarbha-hero-gurbani-reflects-on-dream-come-true-moment', <p class="title">Confident India U19 eye fourth World Cup title</p>: 'https://www.bcci.tv/news/2018/news/17091/confident-india-u19-eye-fourth-world-cup-title', but I don't wan't to print <p class="title"> and </p>, I want only the content inside Domestic Interview

Comment: like this {'No club and school cricket in Cape Town as drought worsens ': 'http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-news/100135/no-club-school-cricket-cape-town-drought-south-africa', 'Du Plessis ruled out of India ODIs, T20Is with finger injury': 'http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-news/100134/south-africa-faf-du-plessis-ruled-out-india-cricket-team-odi-t20i-finger-injury-farhaan-behardien-heinrich-klaasen',}

Comment: `div.find('p', {"class":"title"}).text`